# PHP Script Is Being Hijacked

Tags: php, filemaker

First, I am not a php coder so I don't have a clue as to why the following is happening.
I have some php files that a developer created that I use to to a find in Filemaker Webdirect. The php files are suppose to create a connection with Filemaker and display the find in Webdirect.
All of a sudden as of yesterday, running the php script redirected the browser to http://www.searchingresult.com/?pid=9POLWR59T&dn=smilepix.i.com.com&rpid=9POKA9272

The php script has three files: fm_link.php, fm_read.php and fm_write.php that run in that order.

To try and resolve the issue I tried a few things.

1. try and run the script from another computer - same result as above.
2. Place the php scripts on another domain - same result as above.

Here are the script that are run:
fm_link.php

```
    <?php

session_start();

// default parameters, if not passed
$fmurl = ''; // enter the address of the server hosting webdirect
$fmfile = ''; // enter the default file to open

if (isset($_GET['fmurl'])) {
    $fmurl = $_GET['fmurl'];
}
if (isset($_GET['fmfile'])) {
    $fmfile = $_GET['fmfile'];
}


// store all GET paramters in a session
if (isset($_GET) && count($_GET) > 0) {
    $_SESSION['get_requests'] = $_GET;

}

// redirect to WebDirect Session
header('Location: http://' . $fmurl . '/fmi/webd#' . $fmfile );
```

fm_read.php

```
<?php

// check for required parameter, should match the UUID passed in fm write file.
if(isset($_GET['file_uuid']) && strlen($_GET['file_uuid'])>0 ){

    $filename_string = filter_var($_GET['file_uuid'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    $fn = '/tmp/'.$filename_string.'.txt';

    $fr = fopen($fn, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    echo fread($fr, filesize($fn));
    fclose($fr);

    unlink($fn);  // remove the file once read

} else {

    exit('Error: No file.');

}
```

fm_write.php

```
    <?php

    session_start();

    // only write to file if we get the correct parameter "file_uuid"
    if (isset($_GET['file_uuid']) && strlen($_GET['file_uuid']) > 0) {
        // save temp file with uuid from server. sanitize the file_uuid parameter
        $filename_string = filter_var($_GET['file_uuid'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        // add extension for writing
        $filename = $filename_string . '.txt';

        // set session variables to a string to write
        //initialize string
        $string = '';
        // set each parameter as local variable
        foreach ($_SESSION['get_requests'] as $key => $value) {
            if ($key == 'fmurl' || $key == 'fmfile') {
                // do not store these two parameters
            } else {

                // store as variables
                $string .= '$' . urlencode($key) . ' = "' . urlencode($value) . '"; ';
            }
        }

        // write the file to temp
        $fn = '/tmp/' . $filename;
        if ($fn) {
            $f = fopen($fn, 'w+');
            if ($f) {
                $fw = fwrite($f, $string);
                if ($fw) {
                    echo 'wrote file.'; // . $fn
                    // once file is written, destroy session
                    session_destroy();

                } else {
                    echo 'write error';
                }
            } else {
                echo 'open error';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'file error';
        }
    } else {

        exit('nothing to do.');
    }
```

I am at a standstill with this and do not know what to do.

Thanks in advance for your help - Sam

Comment: Just guesswork after a little searching - clear your web browser cache. Ensure no new extensions are added or running and use 'noscript' or or equivalent or  just disable the 'javascript' in the web browser. now try the using the web-site. Same results?

Comment: Thanks Ryan for answering so quickly. I did what you said above, but when disabling javascript I get this message: "You have to enable javascript in your browser to use an application built with Vaadin." Also I have the Filemaker script pause at the point where the issue is happening and in the parameter global field I am getting this: * Domain Sponsor Redirect<br /><br />". I am looking into our modem to see if it has been affected.

Comment: Can you talk with a 'support' person about the issue?

Comment: I got the solution through their web page and his is not really very responsive, but I do not think it is an issue with his php scripts

Comment: At this point, it is getting  'beyond my field of expertise' and i have no extra helpful advice to add. Except maybe 'don't panic'? Just found this: - no idea whether it is useful? [search-results-removal](http://malwaretips.com/blogs/search-results-removal/)

Comment: Thanks - I saw that link, but it is for windows and I am on a Mac.

Comment: I put a deny ip addresss in the .htacess file and that seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

So from the code you're showing, it looks like the only code that could cause the page to redirect the user to a different page is the following line in `fm_link.php`:

```
header('Location: http://' . $fmurl . '/fmi/webd#' . $fmfile );
```

Everything else in the other files is reading and writing to a file on your server, but none of it would cause a redirection.

This also seems like it could be the culprit because it's just accepting information being passed in from whatever form or link you click that triggers the `fm_link.php` file. Whoever hijacked your setup may have placed the malicious code in the form or link that *triggers* `fm_link.php` which doesn't look to be included in the code you're showing.

I don't think the source of your problem is shown in the code that you've posted, but my answer to your post is: **call a professional**.

If you're not a php coder it's fine that you're not sure what's going on and this is a good place to learn, but I wouldn't suggest you try to handle it yourself via StackOverflow. If someone has truly hijacked your code it would be best to have a professional developer look at the overall structure. You may be seeing a symptom of what is actually a larger problem.

You can contact the company I work for, [Skeleton Key](http://www.skeletonkey.com), about helping you out or you can look for another development company by using [FileMaker's Consultant Search](http://developer.filemaker.com/search/). Either way, have a developer check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that where the php is hosted has some apache mod or something that is redirecting the page before your script is even run.

It sounds like this is depending on where your PHP files are hosted, and how they are referenced in the FM file. Is the domain you are using out of date? You might try to point to the location of the php files with an IP address instead.

By the way, I tested the solution hosted on my own server in Chrome and Firefox and both of those worked for me. Firefox is not a supported browser for WebDirect, but this worked.

These files were from the blog post here:
http://www.soliantconsulting.com/blog/2015/01/extending-webdirect-url-parameters

Thanks
Mike